# Count distinct IP addresses per country

Tags: mdx

I have a cube with information about visits to a website with IP addresses and country.

I'd like to retrieve the count of unique IP addresses per country, as in the following tabel.

```
+-------------+----------+
| country     | count IP |
+-------------+----------+
| germany     | 2        |
| netherlands | 3        |
+-------------+----------+
```

But all I came up with so far is this:

```
+-------------+---------------+--------+
| country     | IP            | visits |
+-------------+---------------+--------+
| germany     | 65.49.14.152  | 5      |
|             | 66.55.144.187 | 12     |
| netherlands | 93.114.46.11  | 2      |
|             | 93.115.94.85  | 5      |
|             | 141.105.1.7   | 1      |
+-------------+---------------+--------+
```

which is produced by this query:

```
SELECT 
  NON EMPTY 
    {Hierarchize({[Measures].[Visits]})} ON COLUMNS
 ,NON EMPTY 
    CrossJoin
    (
      [Geografy.Localizacion].[Country].MEMBERS
     ,[RemoteClient].[IP].MEMBERS
    ) ON ROWS
FROM [VisitsCube];
```

How can I modify this query to produce the results as in the first tabel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a calculated member which would hold the counts per unique IP. And from the row axis, remove `[RemoteClient].[IP].Members`.

```
WITH MEMBER Measures.[Count IP] AS
SUM(Distinct(EXISTING [RemoteClient].[IP].Members), [Measures].[Visits])

SELECT NON EMPTY [Geografy.Localizacion].[Country].Members ON 1,
NON EMPTY Measures.[Count IP] ON 0
FROM [VisitsCube]
```

Comment: This works if I remove `EXISTING`. If not: syntax error (on Pentaho Saiku).

Answer (score 0):

In `AdvWrks` I tested this method:

```
WITH 
  MEMBER [Measures].[CountX] AS 
    Sum
    (
      [Customer].[Customer Geography].[City]
     ,IIF
      (
       NOT isempty([Measures].[Internet Sales Amount])
       ,1
       ,null
      )
    ) 
SELECT 
  {[Measures].[CountX]} ON 0
 ,NON EMPTY 
      [Product].[Product Categories].[Category]
 ON 1
FROM [Adventure Works]
WHERE 
  [Geography].[Geography].[Country].&[Canada];
```

It gives the count of the number of cities where there was Internet Sales Amoutn for each product category:

[image]

Applying to your situation I think it is like this:

```
WITH 
  MEMBER [Measures].[CountX] AS 
    Sum
    (
      [RemoteClient].[IP].MEMBERS
     ,IIF
      (
       NOT isempty([Measures].[Visits])
       ,1
       ,null
      )
    ) 
SELECT 
  NON EMPTY 
    [Geografy.Localizacion].[Country].MEMBERS ON 1
 ,NON EMPTY 
    [Measures].[CountX] ON 0
FROM [VisitsCube];
```